# Are @, ! symbols are safe for url and routing configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xml, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some urls formed like in my router mapping

```
/section/{{some_section_name}}
/topic/{{some_topic_name}}
```

Now I am thinking to convert the section into shorted by
`/!{{some_section_name}}` to avoid the explicit spelling of `/section`

Similarly I would like to use 
`/@{{some_topic_name}}` instead of `/topic/{{some_topic_name}}`

I believe that browser shall not encode these characters by its own. Is it OK to use ! and @ symbols in the route as mentioned above? Please give me side effects using such a conventions in the web.

Comment: @Thank you Tim for nice editing. I will do this by my own from next time..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` character has special meaning on a URL - it is a separator between the (optional) username/password and the host name:

```
//<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
```

See section 3.1 of RFC [1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

So, though not strictly a problem for MVC as such, it is more of an issue with the URL schema.

---

For HTTP there is no such restriction on the `!` character. The allowed characters are listed in the RFC linked above.